# Styling a table in html

Tags: html, css

I am new in CSS.I have a Table Like this

```
<table id="datatable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>2013</strong></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><strong>144</strong></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>2012</strong></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><strong>159</strong></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><strong>2011</strong></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><strong>147</strong></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>2010</strong></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><strong>137</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>2009</strong></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><strong>303</strong></td>
        </tr>
```

And I need to style this table as shown below.I have tried something but I can't able to style like that

[image]

I just tried

```
.datatable td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Based on the image below,I need first td border as green and others are black.
Can any one help?Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: vorder-bottom?...is this writing mistake or actually you did it?correct it to border

Comment: Check this out, it's a really nice walkthrough of what can be accomplished. http://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code, `datatable` is an `ID` not a `class`. Update your CSS like below.

```
 #datatable tr:first-child td{
   border-bottom:1px solid green;
 }

 #datatable tr td{
   border-bottom:1px solid black;
 }
 #datatable
 {
  border-collapse:collapse;
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZA9bJ/1/)

Answer (score 3):

try this one

```
      <table class="datatable">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td ><strong>2013</strong></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><strong>144</strong></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>2012</strong></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><strong>159</strong></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><strong>2011</strong></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><strong>147</strong></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>2010</strong></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><strong>137</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>2009</strong></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><strong>303</strong></td>
                </tr>
   </table>
```

In css

```
 .datatable td{
 border-bottom:1px solid black;
 }
.datatable
 {
 border-collapse:collapse;
 }
.datatable tr:first-child td{
color:green;
border-bottom:1px solid green;
}
```

You can see it from here
http://jsfiddle.net/ZKv68/2/

Answer (score 1):

use this css

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vhdrl)

```
.green {
 color: green;
}
#datatable td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#datatable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.` represents class..`#` represents id...so, change `.database` to `#database` in css.

try this:

```
<tr class=green>
            <td><strong>2013</strong></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><strong>144</strong></td>

        </tr>

<tr class=black>
            <td><strong>2012</strong></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><strong>159</strong></td>

        </tr>
```

and in css:

```
#datatable tr.green {
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}

#datatable tr.black {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following CSS in your styles

```
#datatable{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#datatable td{
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    color:#000;
}

#datatable tbody tr:first-child td{
    color:#00FF00;
}
```

here is a live example

http://jsfiddle.net/Ycyyn/

Answer (score 1):

look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5ep8D/)

```
#datatable{
    border-collapse:collapse; 
}
#datatable td{
   padding-left:4px;
    padding-right:4px;
}
#datatable tr{
color:#444444;
border-bottom:2px solid #999999;
}
#datatable tr:first-child{
color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `<table id="datatable">` here you declare an ID and in your CSS  `.datatable td` a class. You have to use `#` for selecting IDs

Just add this CSS:

```
#datatable tr:first-child td{
   border-bottom:1px solid green;
   color:green;
}

#datatable td{
   border-bottom:1px solid black;
}

#datatable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/A6RT6/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your CSS. Use #datatable instead of .datatable.

Apply a class or ID to your first row and use something like:

```
<tr class="green">
    <td><strong>2013</strong></td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td><strong>144</strong></td>
 </tr>
```

CSS:

```
.green{
    color:green; 
}
```

You can also use

```
table tr:first-child {
    color:green;
}
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

If you are using id, then you need to use # to reference it in CSS. Dot is for class.
To reference just the first row, you can use 'first-child'

Example:

```
#datatable td{
 border-bottom:1px solid black;
}

#datatable tr:first-child td {
 border-bottom:1px solid green;
}
```